# angularjs select ng-options default value with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html-select

I want to set an init option to a select field in angularjs. My problem is that my options came from an array and my default option should be from another array. Here's my code:

```
<select ng-model="userorg.organizations" class="form-control" name="organizations" ng-options="o.name for o in org">
  <option value="{{ org._links.parent.href }}">{{ own.name }}</option>
</select>
```

and in my js file:

```
$http.get('api/identity/organizations/').success(function(data) {
    $scope.org = data._embedded.organizations;
})

$http.get('user').success(function(data) {
    $scope.own = data.organization;
})
```

I hope you know what my problem is.

Comment: According to the `ng-options` you wrote, it appears that `$scope.org` is an *array*. But this is in contradiction with `org._links...` that you set for the default value, as if `org` was an object. Could you precise what you want?

Comment: thees are two differend json resluts. the first lists the chlild organizations of the root org and the second lists the root organization. and i want to set the the root org to the selected one and the others can be chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a workaround for my problem

js file:

```
    $http.get('user').success(function(data) {
    $scope.ownOrg = data.organization.name;
})

$scope.add = function(){
    // Check witch Organization is chosen
    // ***********************************
    if($scope.data.organizations) {
        $scope.data.organizations = $scope.data.organizations;
        var link = $scope.data.organizations._links.self.href.replace("/uaa/", '/');
    } else {
        console.log($scope.user);
        var link = $scope.users[0]._links.organization.href.replace("/uaa/", '/');
    } ...
```

and in html

```
 <select ng-model="data.organizations" class="form-control" name="organizations" ng-options="o.name for o in org">
                                    <option value="">{{ ownOrg }}</option>
                                </select>
```

this works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<select ng-model="userorg.organizations" class="form-control" name="organizations" ng-init="o.name[0]" ng-options="o.name for o in org track by     $index">
  <option value="{{ org._links.parent.href }}">{{ own.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your model, `userorg.organizations` to the initial item you'd like to have in the dropdown box.

Note: Because AngularJS needs your ng-model variable (`userorg.organizations`) to refer to the same object (not a different object with the same value) as the one you would like selected in the ng-options array (`org`), you may need to iterate through your `org` array to find the object that "matches" your default object.

Assuming all names of organizations are unique, you could modify your user http success function like this:

```
$http.get('user').success(function(data) {
    $scope.own = data.organization;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.org.length; i++) {
      if($scope.org[i].name == $scope.own.name) {
        $scope.userorg.organizations = $scope.org[i]
      }
    }
})
```